# Regarding text to speech with real human voice in offline mode and if online then free

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech

Currently i am developing application related to speech text. For this i used text to speech of android. But it is not doing speech like a person speaks. 
So there is any library or way to speech my text like real person's speaks. Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your best option is something like Wavenet. tts is *really* hard and making it sound *just like a human* is damn near impossible. The best I've heard is definitely wavenet.

Comment: https://github.com/gotev/android-speech

Comment: https://github.com/bradleybossard/android-speech-to-text-demo

Comment: Did you _google_ this?

Comment: @Deepak Kamat yes but not found exact that i wants

Comment: @Clearer and Nilesh Rathod i will implement your suggestion. and thanks.

Comment: Try this http://www.fromtexttospeech.com/

Comment: @chetanprajapat You can try this project: https://github.com/RakshitSorathiya/GoogleSpeech. This may help you with your requirements.

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya thanks for suggestion. Do you have any offline library suggestion?

Comment: @chetanprajapat This project even works offline. Its very easy to implement.

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya thank you so much

Comment: @chetanprajapat You welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use IBM Watson's TTS [For natural voices to be used](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/text-to-speech/)

Make an account in IBM and use it's API..free for 1 month.

Comment: i need offline mode tts